# want to add new label on each time i draw new rectangle in canvas as userInput text or prompt

Tags: angular, typescript, project

It is an angular project. This is my HTML-file:

```
<div class="container">
  <img
    src="assets\ONT-Digital-Prescriber-Orders-Form-(smartpaper-MPGL).png"
    class="background-image"
    alt="no image to show"
  />
  <div class="canvas-section">
    <canvas #canvas> </canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info-section">
  <h2>Info section:</h2>
  <div class="starting-point-box" *ngIf="getStartPoint()">
    <h5>1.Starting Points:</h5>
    <p>X-Axis: {{ getStartPoint()?.x | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
    <p>Y-Axis: {{ getStartPoint()?.y | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dimensions-box" *ngIf="currentHeight && currentWidth">
    <h5>2.Shape:</h5>
    <p>Height: {{ currentHeight | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
    <p>Width: {{ currentWidth | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
    <p>
      <span><h5>3.Area is:</h5></span>
      {{ currentHeight * currentWidth | number : "1.0-`0" }} unit
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h5>4.Draw Shape Manually:</h5>
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="startingX">Starting X: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="startingX"
          value=""
          placeholder="Enter you point"
          [(ngModel)]="startingX"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="startingY">Starting Y: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="startingY"
          value=""
          placeholder="Enter your point"
          [(ngModel)]="startingY"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="rectangleWidth">Width: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="rectangleWidth"
          value=""
          [(ngModel)]="rectangleWidth"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="rectangleHeight">Height: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="rectangleHeight"
          value=""
          [(ngModel)]="rectangleHeight"
        />
      </div>
      <button class="button-click" (click)="drawUserRectangle()">
        Draw Shape
      </button> 
      <h5>5. Erase all the shapes:</h5>
      <button class="click-erase" (click)="deleteAllRectangles()">
        Clear Shape
      </button>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my TS-**strong text**file:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

interface RectangleData {
  startPoint: fabric.Point;
  endPoint: fabric.Point;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  area: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.css'],
})
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: true })
  canvasRef!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  imgElement = document.getElementsByClassName('background-image');
  private canvas!: fabric.Canvas;
  private isDrawing: boolean = false;
  private rectanglesStore: RectangleData[] = [];
  private isMovingRect: boolean = false; // Flag to indicate if we are moving an existing rectangle
  private startPoint: fabric.Point | null = null;
  private currentRect: fabric.Rect | null = null;
  private label: fabric.Text | null = null;
  private isMovingRectStarted: boolean = false;
  private labels: fabric.Text[] = [];

  private labelFontWeight: number = 5;
  private labelFontSize: number = 20;

  currentHeight: number = 0;
  currentWidth: number = 0;

  // for drawing rectangle as user input
  startingX: number = 0;
  startingY: number = 0;
  rectangleWidth: number = 0;
  rectangleHeight: number = 0;
  nextRectangleId: number = 1;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const imgElement = document.querySelector(
      '.background-image'
    ) as HTMLImageElement;
    imgElement.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.width = imgElement.width;
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.height = imgElement.height;
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid black';

      this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.canvasRef.nativeElement, {
        isDrawingMode: false,
      });

      this.canvas.setBackgroundImage(
        imgElement.src,
        this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas)
      );

      this.canvas.on('mouse:down', (options: fabric.IEvent) => {
        this.onMouseDown(options);
        console.log('down');
      });

      this.canvas.on('mouse:move', (options: fabric.IEvent) => {
        this.onMouseMove(options);
        console.log('move');
      });

      this.canvas.on('mouse:up', (options: fabric.IEvent) => {
        this.onMouseUp(options);
        console.log('up');
      });
    });
  }

  getStartPoint(): fabric.Point | null {
    return this.startPoint;
  }

  updateDimensions() {
    if (this.currentRect) {
      this.currentHeight = Math.abs(this.currentRect?.height ?? 0);
      this.currentWidth = Math.abs(this.currentRect?.width ?? 0);
    } else {
      this.currentHeight = 0;
      this.currentWidth = 0;
    }
  }

  rectangleName = window.prompt('please name the rectangle');
  

  showLabel(rect: fabric.Rect) {
    const rectCenter = rect.getCenterPoint();
    const labelText = this.rectangleName ?? ''; // Provide an empty string as default if this.rectangleName is null
    const label = new fabric.Text(labelText, {
      left: rectCenter.x,
      top: rectCenter.y,
      fontSize: this.labelFontSize,
      fontWeight: this.labelFontWeight,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'bottom',
    });

    // Check if the rectangle is actually drawn (has non-zero width and height)
    if (rect.width !== 0 && rect.height !== 0) {
      this.labels.push(label);

      if (this.label) {
        this.canvas.remove(this.label);
      }

      this.label = label;

      this.canvas.add(this.label);
    }
  }

  onMouseDown(options: fabric.IEvent) {
    console.log(options);
    if (options.target && options.target.type === 'rect') {
      // Mouse is over an existing rectangle, set the flag to true
      this.isMovingRect = true;
      this.currentRect = options.target as fabric.Rect;
      this.startPoint = this.currentRect.getCenterPoint();

      this.canvas.add(this.currentRect);
      this.showLabel(this.currentRect);
    } else {
      // Mouse is not over an existing rectangle, create a new one
      this.isDrawing = true;
      const pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(options.e);
      this.startPoint = new fabric.Point(pointer.x, pointer.y);
      this.currentRect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: this.startPoint.x,
        top: this.startPoint.y,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
        strokeWidth: 2,
      });

      if (this.label) {
        this.canvas.add(this.label);
      }

      this.showLabel(this.currentRect);
      this.canvas.add(this.currentRect);
      this.updateDimensions();
    }
  }

  onMouseMove(options: fabric.IEvent) {
    if (this.isMovingRect) {
      // If moving an existing rectangle, update its position
      const pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(options.e);
      const deltaX = pointer.x - this.startPoint!.x;
      const deltaY = pointer.y - this.startPoint!.y;

      const newLeft = this.currentRect!.left! + deltaX;
      const newTop = this.currentRect!.top! + deltaY;
      const canvasWidth = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.width;
      const canvasHeight = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.height;
      const rectWidth = this.currentRect!.width!;
      const rectHeight = this.currentRect!.height!;

      // Check if the new position is inside the canvas boundary
      if (
        newLeft >= 0 &&
        newTop >= 0 &&
        newLeft + rectWidth <= canvasWidth &&
        newTop + rectHeight <= canvasHeight
      ) {
        this.currentRect!.set({
          left: newLeft,
          top: newTop,
        });

        const rectCenter = this.currentRect!.getCenterPoint();
        if (this.label) {
          this.label.set({ left: rectCenter.x, top: rectCenter.y });
        }

        this.canvas.renderAll();
      }
    } else if (this.isDrawing) {
      // If drawing a new rectangle, update its size
      const pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(options.e);
      const canvasWidth = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.width;
      const canvasHeight = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.height;

      let rectLeft = Math.min(this.startPoint!.x, pointer.x);
      let rectTop = Math.min(this.startPoint!.y, pointer.y);
      let rectWidth = Math.abs(pointer.x - this.startPoint!.x);
      let rectHeight = Math.abs(pointer.y - this.startPoint!.y);

      // Make sure the rectangle stays inside the canvas boundaries
      if (rectLeft < 0) {
        rectWidth += rectLeft;
        rectLeft = 0;
      }
      if (rectTop < 0) {
        rectHeight += rectTop;
        rectTop = 0;
      }
      if (rectLeft + rectWidth > canvasWidth) {
        rectWidth = canvasWidth - rectLeft;
      }
      if (rectTop + rectHeight > canvasHeight) {
        rectHeight = canvasHeight - rectTop;
      }

      const isOverlap = this.checkForRectangleOverlap(
        rectLeft,
        rectTop,
        rectWidth,
        rectHeight
      );

      if (this.currentRect && rectWidth > 0 && rectHeight > 0 && !isOverlap) {
        this.currentRect.set({
          left: rectLeft,
          top: rectTop,
          width: rectWidth,
          height: rectHeight,
        });
        this.showLabel(this.currentRect);

        const rectCenter = this.currentRect.getCenterPoint();
        if (this.label) {
          this.label.set({ left: rectCenter.x, top: rectCenter.y });
        }

        this.canvas.renderAll();

        this.currentHeight = Math.abs(rectHeight);
        this.currentWidth = Math.abs(rectWidth);
      }

      this.updateDimensions();
    }
  }

  checkForRectangleOverlap(
    newLeft: number,
    newTop: number,
    newWidth: number,
    newHeight: number
  ): boolean {
    // Loop through the existing rectangles and check for overlap with the new rectangle
    for (const existingRect of this.rectanglesStore) {
      const existingLeft = existingRect.startPoint.x;
      const existingTop = existingRect.startPoint.y;
      const existingWidth = existingRect.width;
      const existingHeight = existingRect.height;

      // Check if the new rectangle overlaps the existing rectangle
      const isOverlap =
        newLeft + newWidth >= existingLeft &&
        newLeft <= existingLeft + existingWidth &&
        newTop + newHeight >= existingTop &&
        newTop <= existingTop + existingHeight;

      if (isOverlap) {
        return true; // Return true if there's an overlap
      }
    }

    return false; // Return false if no overlap is found
  }

  onMouseUp(options: fabric.IEvent) {
    if (this.isMovingRect) {
      // Mouse was used to move the rectangle, reset the flag
      this.isMovingRect = false;
      this.isMovingRectStarted = false;
      if (this.currentRect !== null) {
        this.showLabel(this.currentRect);
      }
    } else {
      // Mouse was used to create a new rectangle, set the flag to false
      this.isDrawing = false;
      this.isMovingRectStarted = false;
      this.updateDimensions();

      // Check if the rectangle has a non-zero width and height
      if (this.currentWidth !== 0 && this.currentHeight !== 0) {
        if (this.currentRect && this.startPoint) {
          const endPoint = new fabric.Point(
            this.startPoint.x + this.currentWidth,
            this.startPoint.y + this.currentHeight
          );
          const area = this.currentWidth * this.currentHeight;
          const newRectangle: RectangleData = {
            startPoint: this.startPoint,
            endPoint: endPoint,
            width: this.currentWidth,
            height: this.currentHeight,
            area: area,
          };
          if (this.label) {
            this.canvas.add(this.label);
          }

          this.showLabel(this.currentRect);

          this.rectanglesStore.push(newRectangle);
          console.log(this.rectanglesStore);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  drawUserRectangle() {
    const startX = this.startingX;
    const startY = this.startingY;
    const width = this.rectangleWidth;
    const height = this.rectangleHeight;

    this.drawRectangle(height, width, startX, startY);
  }

  removeRectanglesFromCanvas() {
    const objects = this.canvas.getObjects();
    objects.forEach((object) => {
      if (object.type === 'rect') {
        this.canvas.remove(object);
      }
    });
  }
  // for clearing all the objects on the canvas
  deleteAllRectangles() {
    // Clear the rectanglesStore array
    this.rectanglesStore = [];
    console.log(this.rectanglesStore);

    // Remove all rectangles from the canvas
    this.removeRectanglesFromCanvas();

    // Remove all labels from the canvas
    this.removeLabelsFromCanvas();

    // Clear the currentRect and startPoint
    this.currentRect = null;
    this.startPoint = null;

    // Clear the dimensions and label
    this.currentHeight = 0;
    this.currentWidth = 0;
    if (this.label) {
      this.canvas.remove(this.label);
      this.label = null;
    }
  }
  // for clearing all the lables of the recatngle
  removeLabelsFromCanvas() {
    this.labels.forEach((label) => {
      this.canvas.remove(label);
    });
    this.labels = [];
  }

  drawRectangle(height: number, width: number, startX: number, startY: number) {
    this.currentRect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: startX,
      top: startY,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      fill: 'transparent',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
      strokeWidth: 2,
    });

    this.canvas.add(this.currentRect);

    this.currentHeight = Math.abs(height);
    this.currentWidth = Math.abs(width);

    this.startPoint = new fabric.Point(startX, startY);

    this.canvas.renderAll();
  }

}
```

right now what happening is a pop up will come and by filling a text in it than in every rectangle the value reamins the same , what i want is each i draw new rectangle and that time a pop up will show up by filling that input than that text should shows up on the screen

```
<div class="container">
  <img
    src="assets\ONT-Digital-Prescriber-Orders-Form-(smartpaper-MPGL).png"
    class="background-image"
    alt="no image to show"
  />
  <div class="canvas-section">
    <canvas #canvas> </canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info-section">
  <h2>Info section:</h2>
  <div class="starting-point-box" *ngIf="getStartPoint()">
    <h5>1.Starting Points:</h5>
    <p>X-Axis: {{ getStartPoint()?.x | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
    <p>Y-Axis: {{ getStartPoint()?.y | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dimensions-box" *ngIf="currentHeight && currentWidth">
    <h5>2.Shape:</h5>
    <p>Height: {{ currentHeight | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
    <p>Width: {{ currentWidth | number : "1.0-0" }} unit</p>
    <p>
      <span><h5>3.Area is:</h5></span>
      {{ currentHeight * currentWidth | number : "1.0-0" }} unit
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h5>4.Draw Shape Manually:</h5>
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="startingX">Starting X: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="startingX"
          value=""
          placeholder="Enter you point"
          [(ngModel)]="startingX"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="startingY">Starting Y: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="startingY"
          value=""
          placeholder="Enter your point"
          [(ngModel)]="startingY"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="rectangleWidth">Width: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="rectangleWidth"
          value=""
          [(ngModel)]="rectangleWidth"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="rectangleHeight">Height: </label>
        <input
          class="Input-field"
          type="number"
          id="rectangleHeight"
          value=""
          [(ngModel)]="rectangleHeight"
        />
      </div>
      <button class="button-click" (click)="drawUserRectangle()">
        Draw Shape
      </button> 
      <h5>5. Erase all the shapes:</h5>
      <button class="click-erase" (click)="deleteAllRectangles()">
        Clear Shape
      </button>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help?